# Migrate from Gnote to Org-mode

Tags: emacs, gnote, org-mode

I have lots of notes in Gnote and I consider to use [Org-mode](http://orgmode.org/) instead. How can I migrate my Gnote notes to Org-mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used https://github.com/StAlphonsos/scriptologie/blob/develop/scripts/tomboy2org.pl which is mentioned in http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tools/.

Here is how to proceed. (Note, however, that you may want to clean out your notes before so that you do not migrate unwanted notes.)

1. Install [the dependencies](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/45252) for running the script:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libxml-twig-perl libtext-format-perl
   ```
2. Download the script from https://github.com/StAlphonsos/scriptologie/blob/develop/scripts/tomboy2org.pl.
3. Close Gnote so that any changes is written to its database.
4. Run the script. I chose to run the script with the option `-notebooks` to make one .org file out of each Gnote notebook:

   ```
   perl tomboy2org.pl -notebooks -verbose
   ```

Answer (score -1):

there's a script available @ orgmode
[Org Mode tools](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tools/index.html)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. As noted, it is not a complete answer but merely a pointer to a solution (which would do better as a comment). Since you did not write up a solution I decided to document my solution. See http://askubuntu.com/a/90392/19490.

Comment: Welcome to our community! As noted by Marco Ceppi and N.N This is not a real answer but just a link...